# Not able to filter buttons based on specific character in their text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this demo. Why am I not able to use the `:contains()` properly here to only select buttons which contains the text `filter` ?

As you can see right now even with passing `x` I am still getting `there is a filter item` which is not correct as there is now `x` in any of the buttons

```js
var filter = 'x';
if ($('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:contains(' + filter + ')')) {
  console.log(" There is a  Filter");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
  <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
  <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
  <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calls to `$(` will return a jQuery collection, and objects/collections are *never* falsey, even if empty, so your `if` check will always be fulfilled at the moment. Check whether the `length` is 0 instead:

```js
function checkFilter(filter) {
  const jqCollection = $('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:contains(' + filter + ')');
  if (jqCollection.length) {
    console.log(" There is a Filter for " + filter);
  }
}
checkFilter('x');
checkFilter('A');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
  <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
  <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
  <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
</div>
```

The time the following will *not* be fulfilled:

```
if (cond) {
```

is if `cond` is `false`, `0`, the empty string, `NaN`, `null`, or `undefined`. For any other values, the inner block will run.